# why my scrapy response body returns a favicon.ico

Tags: python, scrapy

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.  I have tried some webs but there is one can't pass, it returns `favicon.ico`

For example, I try and crawl the following URL from the scrapy shell:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://baijia.baidu.com"
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: tutorial)
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'}
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware']
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.extensions.httpcache] DEBUG: Using filesystem cache storage in /home/suocheng/My_Scrapy/tutorial/.scrapy/httpcache
2017-12-04 20:37:51 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://baijia.baidu.com> (referer: None) ['cached']
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x2ebbc10>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://baijia.baidu.com>
[s]   response   <200 https://baijia.baidu.com>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x2ebbb90>
[s]   spider     <DefaultSpider 'default' at 0x33634d0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   fetch(url[, redirect=True]) Fetch URL and update local objects (by default, redirects are followed)
[s]   fetch(req)                  Fetch a scrapy.Request and update local objects 
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>> response.body
'favicon.ico'
>>>
```

it returns `favicon.ico`.
and if i set the Xpath like this:

```
>>> response.xpath('/html/head/title')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py", line 105, in xpath
    raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text")
NotSupported: Response content isn't text
```

so how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it doesn't return `favicon.ico` - it returns string with text "favicon.ico". Maybe server has strong security system and sends it when it thinks you are bot, not human. `xpath` needs `HTML/XML` file.

Comment: ah?It returns the string?not the icon?I thought it returns the favicon.ico.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this sever sends file with string `favicon.ico` if you have incorrect `USER-AGENT`

Try with extra option which looks like correct `USER-AGENT` and you get `HTML` file.

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0" https://baijia.baidu.com
```

And then `response.xpath` will work.

```
In [1]: response.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract_first()
Out[1]: '首页-百家号'
```

You can get better `USER-AGENT` from your browser using page [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/)

Comment: sorry,I still get the same error,and i've tried USER_AGENT=''Chrome/62.0.3202.94'',''Safari/537.36","Mozilla/5.0".it still returns 'favicon.ico'

Comment: Maybe it checks something else but I don't know what it could be. Do you have problem when you run this page in web browser ? You can use `httpbin.org` to see all headers send from browser and use them in scrapy.

Comment: It does not happen in web browser.I'll try the way you just say and find a way to check the headers that the scrapy have sent.Maybe it send something different from the browesr.Thank you anyway.

Comment: you can use `scrapy` to get data from `httpbin.org/headers` and you should get headers used by `scrapy`

Comment: BTW: in scrapy documentation you can see [DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#default-request-headers)